# Size of input allowed in AllenNLP - Predict when using a Predictor

Tags: pytorch, prediction, allennlp

does anyone has an idea what is the input text size limit that can be passed to the
predict(passage, question) method of the AllenNLP Predictors.

I have tried with passage of 30-40 sentences, which is working fine. But eventually it is not working for me when I am passing some significant amount of text around 5K statement.

Answer (score 0):

Which model are you using? Some models truncate the input, others try to handle arbitrary length input using a sliding window approach. With the latter, the limit will depend on the memory available on your system.

Comment: Hi @petew, I am making use of transformer-qa and bidaf-model. My input contains around 2Million tokens. The system I am using 24vcpus, 448GiB Memory.

Comment: The question is really, what's the longest sequence you ever try to send into the model?